# MSAL with Graph API

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to build a Java code to create users in AAD using MSAL and MS Graph API. Below is the code that I am using to create the user. I am able to retrieve the token successfully, however getting exception while trying to POST the request. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();      
         params.put("givenName", "Test");
         params.put("displayName", "ABC");
         params.put("accountEnabled", true);
         params.put("mailNickname","abc");
         params.put("userPrincipalName","jcooper@demo.onmicrosoft.com");    
         StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
         for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
             if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
             postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
             postData.append('=');
             postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
         }
         byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
int length =postDataBytes.length;
        URL url = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);
      conn.setDoInput(true);
      conn.setDoOutput(true);
      conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
       conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",Integer.toString(length));
        conn.connect();      
        conn.getInputStream();
        try (var wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.write(postDataBytes);
        }
        StringBuilder content;     
        System.out.println(postDataBytes+" "+postData);
        try (var br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;
            content = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(line);
                content.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
       }
        System.out.println(content.toString());
    }
```

Exception : Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 411 for URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

Comment: (1) If you're using MSAL for Java then you can enable the trace/inbuilt telemetry logging to see in which API call you're seeing the issue. (2) Share the detailed error/trace that you get

Answer (score 0):

According to some test, I met the same issue with yours. It seems the code is correct but do not know why it still show 411 error. It may be caused by the graph api can just accept json request body but you convert the request body to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in your first part of code(I'm not sure because I test the code with json request body but still show 411).

Since you mentioned use MSAL to get access token, you can also continue to use MSAL to create the user. Please refer to this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#example):

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

User user = new User();
user.accountEnabled = true;
user.displayName = "Adele Vance";
user.mailNickname = "AdeleV";
user.userPrincipalName = "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
PasswordProfile passwordProfile = new PasswordProfile();
passwordProfile.forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true;
passwordProfile.password = "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d";
user.passwordProfile = passwordProfile;

graphClient.users()
    .buildRequest()
    .post(user);
```

Comment: One question....which should be the preferred method, use MSAL or graphClient for access token?

Comment: @SushmitaDas I'm sorry that not describe the solution clearly. If you use MSAL, you do not need to get access token in your code. You can choose an authentication provider from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=Java#ClientCredentialsProvider), for example "client credential provider". And then continue to use MSAL code which I provided above to create user.

Comment: I need your help to understand the difference between the reference link provided by you and [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-daemon/blob/master/msal-client-credential-secret/src/main/java/ClientCredentialGrant.java) . The latter is getting an access token using MSAL and the former is using the client credential flow as authentication provider. What is the difference between both? Which one is recommended?

Comment: @SushmitaDas Sorry for delay reply. Both of them can implement the requirement, and they are almost same in backend. The difference is the first sample I provided doesn't get access token in code. But actually `graphClient` already contains the access token in it, so it can do the get/create user operation. The second link you provided get the access token in the code and then use a HTTP request the do the same operation(get/create user).

Comment: Hi @SushmitaDas Any update about this post or any other questions ? If do not have any other questions, could you please mark the answer as "accepted", thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing Microsoft Graph from a **desktop app**, I'd use the `InteractiveBrowserCredentialBuilder()` with the `TokenCredentialAuthProvider` that comes with GraphSDK to get the Graph token. Check out the great [sample code here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java#InteractiveProvider). All you'd need to do to customize this is to  change the last line and set the scopes differently based on what Graph API you need to call. There's a link on the bottom of that page that'll teach you to register your app properly.

The simplest way in a **web app** is to use **Azure AD Spring Boot Starter** to get an access token for a logged-in user, and use GraphSDK to call Graph in a Spring 5 web app. See [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-spring-tutorial/tree/main/2-Authorization-I/call-graph) that demonstrates this along with full instructions (Relevant Graph code is is in SampleController.java and Utilities.java)